# How does this map work in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
map < string, int > m;
char line[32];
int main(void){
    int n, t;
    for(scanf("%d", &t); t--; ){
        m.clear();
        for(scanf("%d\n", &n); n--; ){
            fgets(line, 32, stdin);
            line[32] = 0;
            ++m[line];
        }
        map < string, int >::iterator it;
        for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
            printf("%s%d\n", it->first.c_str(), it->second);
        if(t) puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This basically accepts a number of strings and outputs them in sorted order along with their frequency. I have a doubt. A map is being used here. So, it accepts a string in the character array and then directly increments at that particular position of map. Isn't insertion of that string at that position of the map required? Like,

```
 string s = line;
 m.insert(pair<string,int>(s,1);
```

Can we directly increment at that position without inserting it first? Sorry, if this is a basic doubt but I am new to learning C++.

Comment: `line[32] = 0;` is out-of-range

Comment: I get that your'e new to C++, so I'll try to say this as teacher-ly as possible.  Always read the documentation first.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator[]` of the `std::map` search for a **value** with the parameter **key**, if exist return the **value**, if not exist, insert the **key** with a **default constructed value** and returned the newly created value.

The line: `++m[line]` check if a **(key, value)** exist in the map with the parameter key, if exits return the frequency, if not insert the line with value `0` (*default value of int*).

Other recommendations, if are programming in C++, use C++ in all the source.

- In/Out with `std::cin` and `std::cout`
- Read lines with `std::getline` and using `std::string`
- In C++ main don't have to take `void` as parameter when not parameters are used (`int main()`) is the standard way.

Answer (score 2):

You are using indexed access in to the `map`:

```
++m[line];
```

Using indexed access always inserts a new default value if the key doesn't yet exist.

Read the docs:  [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)